# unable to create a user in JXplorer for LDAP - i get an error

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to user openLDAP for the very first time. So I found this nice tutorial http://soswin-techbits.blogspot.com/2011/10/installing-openldap-on-windows-7.html. So i followed the instructions all the way to end. However, on the very last step I get an error. When i try to add a user to the group people I get this errpr "Unable to perform Modify Operation."

So after i do cn=user1 then in the Table Editor I type "surname" and hit submit then I get this error.

even when I tried to add a new directorey I get the same error. 
Here is a detailed error.

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]; remaining name 'dc=Organization,dc=com'

What is wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The server may not be configured to host a backend with the suffix `dc=Organization,dc=com`.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I don't understand what you mean. are you saying that the dc=Organization,dc=com is not already existing in his database, or are you saying that somehow a database is incapable of containing those values without special configuration?